# Can I reuse marinade that was used on precooked meat?

Tags: food-safety

Can I reuse Greek marinade that I used on precooked ribs ?

Comment: Hello Vivian! The content of your marinade doesn't matter for the answer. It is important to state in the title what the problem is though, and especially with this question, because if people assume it's about marinated used on uncooked meat, they will vote to close as a duplicate. So I changed your title.